# How to fix symbols/labels in a tiled WMS?

Tags: qgis-server

I have a postgis stored dataset that is consumed in a qgis project and served on qgis server. I noticed however that symbols and labels of point features that overlap 2 tiles of the map are only rendered in the tile that actually contains the feature. Is there some kind of buffering option or a configuration option for rendering to fix this?

[image]

Comment: So are you serving using qgis server as wms server and a tiles server in the middle?

Comment: Yes. Qgis server via mod fcgid on ubuntu server, client web application uses openlayers 2.12 to access the WMS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, solved it, check the post [HERE](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2012-March/015747.html)

Bottomline, you cant do anything on the serverside at this point, so what i did is, put the labels on a separate overlaying layer and made it render in a single tile.

Comment: Link no longer works